# Creating XSLT for Group Data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML data like this:

```
<data ItemCount="5">
<zrow GroupName="Manager"User="User1" />
<zrow GroupName="Developer"User="User2" />
<zrow GroupName="Manager"User="User3" />
<zrow GroupName="CEO"User="User4" />
<zrow GroupName="CEO"User="User5" />
</data>
```

I want output like this:

```
Manager

User1

User3

Developer

User2

CEO

User4

User5
```

What should be my XSLT? I want to create an XSLT which should transform my data to the above format. Could you please help me create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="zrow" group-by="@GroupName">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@User" separator="&#xa;"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An XSLT 1.0 solution relies on the Muenchian Method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="byGroupName" match="zrow" use="@GroupName"/>
    <xsl:template
        match="zrow[generate-id()=
                    generate-id(key('byGroupName', @GroupName)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@GroupName"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byGroupName', @GroupName)" mode="out"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="zrow" mode="out">
        <xsl:value-of select="@User"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="zrow"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please give output as HTML?

Comment: This works if I have the GroupName field filled with some values.  Could you please update the code to manage if GoupName values doesn't have any value in it??

Comment: @NICK - There are lots and lots of grouping questions on SO. It's one of the most frequently asked questions. I'd suggest searching for more information on the Muenchian Method (if you're using XSLT 1.0) or grouping in general. You should have no trouble finding many good examples. As a hint, it should be pretty straightforward to wrap lines like `<xsl:template match="zrow" mode="out">` with other HTML elements, like this: `<li><xsl:template match="zrow" mode="out"></li>`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion.  Before posting this question, I went to all related questions and examples, but couldn't find a proper solution.  I think going again through won't much help. Anyways, Thanks for your help, it really helped.

Comment: Hi All,

Thank you very much for helping me out and it is working fine.

Just one problem.

In Actual, My XML Data Structure is as below :

 

<my:data ItemCount="5">
<z:row GroupName="Manager"User="User1" />
<z:row GroupName="Developer"User="User2" />
<z:row GroupName="Manager"User="User3" />
<z:row GroupName="CEO"User="User4" />
<z:row GroupName="CEO"User="User5" />
</my:data>
 

Could you please tell me how will I handle the ":" because when I write

 

<xsl:key name="k1" match="z:row" use="@GroupName"/>

It's giving me an error as,

Prefix z is not defined!!